# python highest fuzzy ratio to print line from list

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I have a **list** consisting of **some lines**.I want to print the line matching word 'good' with highest fuzzyratio.

**Problem:** Its only printing word instead of line in the list

Coding:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
c = ['I am python', 'python is good', 'Everyone are humans']
print(max(c, key=lambda a: fuzz.ratio(a, 'good')))
```

Expected Output:

```
python is good
```

I get a single word instead of line of highest fuzzyvalue from the list. Please help to fix my code! Answers will be appreciated!

Comment: Can you also show how you populate `c`?

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems ok, most likely your `c` array is initialized incorrectly and contains words instead of sentences. 
You code should be similar to this:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

c = ['I am python', 'python is good', 'Everyone are humans']
print(max(c, key=lambda a: fuzz.ratio(a, 'good')))
```

Comment: Of course, it works, probably the error is in the definition of `c` as I wrote.

Comment: "probably the error is in the definition of c" should be better in comments.

Comment: Most likely the OP is not proficient in python, that's why I thought it was better to post the code than to pollute the comments with a long list of Q&A

Answer (score 0):

```
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz

c = ['I am python', 'python is good', 'Everyone are humans']
l = [(i,fuzz.ratio(i,'good')) for i in c]
l.sort(key=lambda a: a[1], reverse=True)
```

Comment: This answer may solve the problem but please consider expanding it so that it is useful for future visitors as well. You can explain what was wrong with the OP's code and what you did to fix it.